# Excel Formula help please If match copy vale form cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to update a stock list,

> Column A = Barcode  Column B = Correct Qty
>
> Column C = Barcode  Column D = Incorrect Qty

So i need a formula that if Column C is matched to Column A update Qty in Column D

Can someone please help ?

Comment: A formula isn't able to change a cell other than itself - you wouldn't be able to insert a formula that would change Column D based on the values in A and C, unless the formula was already in D. It sounds like the best approach would be to put the formula in E. Can you clarify exactly what you'd need in each scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a helper column (as Werrf implied by putting a formula in coloumn E). You can always hide this column so that the end user does not see it.

A simple idea for a formula in the Helper coloumn is as follows:

Column A = Barcode 
Column B = Correct Qty 
Column C = Barcode 
Column D = Incorrect Qty  (formula below) 
Column E (hidden helper column) = List of default values for incorrect Qty

*Sample formula for column D*

```
 =IF(C2=A2,"Insert update formula here", E2)
```

This formula basically says, if Column C matches Column A then apply an update formula (of your choice),  otherwise show the values of your helper column E